# Using Linq for max value?

Tags: linq

Hi i'm new to linq and i'm trying to find the maximum size an inteeger can hold.

```
Dim Max As Integer = Convert.Int32((From a In mytable Order By a.Item("myValue") Select a.Item("Integer"))).MaxValue
```

it doesn't seem to be working? I asked a buddy and he said to use linq but i've never used it before.

Comment: Are you looking for the maxvalue of any integer or the max of the integers in your list?

Comment: the max size of an int is int.MaxValue

Comment: Are you looking for the max possible value of all integers or just the integers of your list ?

Comment: -1. Not a clear question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have a full sample in VB here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737922#maxsimp